# C : Realloc doesn't work with dynamic double pointer array

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I am facing some issues regarding a realloc with a double pointer dynamic array.
What I would like to perform is to **add 2 pointers** of **type Flight*** inside the **array** schedule of **type Flight** **.

For that, I am relying on the function `add_flight` in the Functions.c file.
This function asks the user for the airline and flight number values and stores these data in a new `Flight* f`. If the schedule is **null** (no flight yet added) it **allocates** memory for the newly created flight otherwise it **realloc** the size of schedule in order the add the new flight.

**Main.c file:**

```
int main() {
    int choice = 1;
    Flight** schedule = NULL;   

    printf("---AIRPORT MANAGER---");
    schedule = add_flight(schedule);
    printf("\n%s : %d\n", (*schedule)->airline, (*schedule)->flightNumber);
    schedule = add_flight(schedule);
    printf("\n%s : %d\n", (*schedule + 1)->airline, (*schedule)->flightNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

**Functions.c file :**

```
#include "Functions.h"

void mygets(char* s, int maxLength) {
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fgets(s, maxLength, stdin) != NULL) {
        size_t lastIndex = strlen(s) - 1;
        if (s[lastIndex] == '\n')
            s[lastIndex] = '\0';
    }
}

void flush() {
    char buffer;
    while ((buffer = getchar()) != EOF && buffer != '\n');
}

Flight** add_flight(Flight** schedule) {
    Flight* f;
    char buffer[100];

    if ((f = (Flight*)malloc(sizeof(Flight*))) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n\n---FLIGHT CREATION---");
    printf("\nAirline: ");
    mygets(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if ((f->airline = _strdup(buffer)) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(buffer, 0, 100);

    printf("\nFlight number: ");
    scanf("%d", &f->flightNumber);
    flush();

    if (schedule == NULL) {
        if ((schedule = malloc(sizeof(Flight*))) == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }       
        *schedule = f;
    }
    else {
        int numberFlights = ((sizeof(*schedule)) / 4) + 1;
        if ((schedule = realloc(schedule, numberFlights * sizeof(Flight*))) == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        *(schedule + numberFlights -1) = f;
    }

    return schedule;
}
```

The issue comes when the second call of `add_flight` is performed in the main.c

In the `add_flight` function, the data are indeed stored in the new `Flight* f` and then the else statement is considered: the variable `numberFlights` gets the value 2. However, the **realloc doesn't work**, the schedule is **not enlarged** and thus there is still only the first flight stored inside this schedule array. I can't figure out why the second flight is not added inside the schedule.

Can someone explain me why this realloc fails ?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: With `malloc(sizeof(Flight*)` you are reserving space with the size of a pointer, to use the size of the `struct` itself use `malloc(sizeof(Flight))` or better yet: `malloc(sizeof *f)`

Comment: There's no way to tell how many flights there are in your dynamic array with the `sizeof` operator. You must keep track of the number of flights differently, for example with an extra variable or by appending a special sentinel value at the end of all flights. (The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time here, but you want to know how many flights there are at run time, of course.)

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for your answer, I added a variable numberOfFlights which is getting incremented each time I add a flight. However, it still doesn't work, the second flight is not added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time. It cannot be used to determine the size of a dynamically allocated array.

C imposes the burden of keeping track of the actual size of an array onto the programmer. You could kee a separate count variable, but because the actual array and its size belong together, it is useful to store them alongside each other in a struct:

```
typedef struct Flight Flight;
typedef struct Flights Flights;

struct Flight {
    char airline[4];
    int number;
    char dest[4];
};

struct Flights {
    Flight *flight;
    int count;
};
```

Instead of operating on the array, operate on the struct:

```
void add_flight(Flights *fl,
    const char *airline, int number, const char *dest)
{
    int n = fl->count++;        // n is old count; fl->count is new count

    fl->flight = realloc(fl->flight,
        (fl->count + 1) * sizeof(*fl->flight));

    snprintf(fl->flight[n].airline, 4, "%s", airline);
    snprintf(fl->flight[n].dest, 4, "%s", dest);
    fl->flight[n].number = number;
}
```

Intialize the flights struct with `NULL` and a count of zero and don't forget to release the used memory when you're done:

```
int main(void)
{
    Flights fl = {NULL, 0};

    add_flight(&fl, "AF", 5512, "CDG");
    add_flight(&fl, "AA", 1100, "ATL");
    add_flight(&fl, "LH", 6537, "FRA");
    add_flight(&fl, "BA", 8821, "LHR");
    add_flight(&fl, "IB", 1081, "EZE");

    print_flights(&fl);

    free(fl.flight);

    return 0;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://ideone.com/xQ4vBt). Some observations:

- There is no need to distinguish between adding the first and subsequent flights, because `realloc(NULL, size)` behaves exactly like `malloc(size)`.
- It is not very efficient to reallocate the memory for each added item. Instead, you pick a suitable initial array size like 4 or 8, then double the size when you hit the limit. That means that the allocated size and the count may differ and you need an aditional `memsize` field in your flights struct.
- The code above relies on manual initialization and destruction. Usually, you will write "constructor" and "destructor" functions to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and your help @MOehm !
Everything is now working :)

Comment: In my instructions, I have to use a double-pointer in order to use as less memory as possible. Therefore I modify a little your code: the struct flight has now pointers to char variables instead of char. And the flights structure has now the variable Flight** flight instead of Flight* flight.

However, in the function add_flight I don't manage to store the value since the flight is type double pointer. I have tried this: fl->flight[n]->airline = _strdup(airline) but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea to make this working?